# Cannot access public method in type Typescript class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've inherited a typescript react project and I'm unfamiliar with some of the concepts of TS. There is a class being exported like:

```
export class SomeGateway {
  constructor(private url: string){}

  public someMethod() {}
}
```

but whenever i do

```
const whatever = new SomeGateway('www.google.com');
```

and try to access `whatever.someMethod()` it says it doesn't exist, I can see `whatever.url` though. What's the proper way to access `someMethod`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] of code where calling `whatever.someMethod()` doesn't work? The error is not reproducible by simple code, e.g. [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GUIFtgDiKMwA7igJ5wDeAUHIhAHZoxQCuCM0AFGFAEsAbsWBx2UJAC44rQUwDmASmoBfWvThh2AIyQCEsvMACywGAAsIAEx5Ka69bQTNWcUhdFDgUOAF44JjJsYyIScgoeAHJSWIA6BQgIBSRgOJdcKKUAbg0PLx84tGMzSxs7WiA)

Comment: i am not sure what is not working in you example.

Comment: Do you have the complete code (declaration + usage) for this issue? Just tried to reproduce it but it worked like expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind the method

```js
export class SomeGateway {
  constructor(private url: string){
     this.someMethod = thi.someMethod.bind(this);
  }

  public someMethod() {}
}
```